# Printing a new array of primes from a random array?

Tags: arrays, methods, static, primes

Hy there i a beginner in java started 3 weeks ago, im having some problems with this code.

in the main method i have an array containing 10 elements. 
i've already made several methods to like

`public static void println(int[] array)`  ------  to print and array

`public static boolean isPrime(int el)`  ----------- prime test. returns true or false

`public static int countPrimes(int[] array)`  ---  returns back the number of primes in the array.

this is the array

```
int[] array = new int{7,5,7,2,11,-4,5,,10,2}
```

the method im having problems with is:

```
public static int[] primesInArray(int[] array)
  {
   int n = array.length;
   int[] temp = new int[countPrimes(array)];  
   int j = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
       if(isPrime(array[i]))
       { 
         temp[j] = array[i];
         j= j +1;
       }
     }
     return temp;
  }
```

it should return an array of 7 numbers like this `{7,5,7,2,11,5,2}`
but instead i get the original array back.

what am i doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see where you are using temp array? This condition "array[i] % array[i] == 1" would always evalute to true. The logic seems flawed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the purpose of this test?

```
if(array[i] % array[i] == 0 || array[i] % array[i] == 1)
```

`array[i] % array[i]` will always be 0 so your test always returns True.

Shouldn't you instead use the following?

```
if (isPrime(array[i]))
```

Edit:
And as Ravi points out, you don't ever use your temp array! I think you need to change `array[i] = array[j];` to `temp[j] = array[i];` when the corrected `if` test is True.

Comment: Thank you guys, i corrected the primetest and the "temp[j]" array aswell. i works perfectly now